# Obj-, Instance variable used when 'self' is not set to the result of '[(super or self) init...]'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, analyzer

I asked a similar question to this already, but I still can't see the problem?

```
-(id)initWithKeyPadType: (int)value
{
    [self setKeyPadType:value];
    self = [self init];
    if( self != nil )
    {
        //self.intKeyPadType = value;

    }
    return self;
}

- (id)init {

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] 
                                                              autorelease];
    decimalSymbol = [formatter decimalSeparator];
....
```

The warning comes from the line above `Instance variable used while 'self' is not set to the result of '[(super or self) init...]'`

Comment: if I understand right your code, you are using a variable before calling the [super init] and this can mess your memory allocation

Comment: He's not calling super init anywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is technically OK, but at some stage you need to invoke `[super init]`. If your class's `init` method does a lot of common initialisation that other `initWith...` methods utilise, then put your `[super init]` in there. Also, always make sure that the class has been `init`'d before trying to play around with instance variables.

```
- (id) initWithKeyPadType: (int)value
{
    self = [self init]; // invoke common initialisation
    if( self != nil )
    {
        [self setKeyPadType:value];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init]; // invoke NSObject initialisation (or whoever superclass is)
    if (!self) return nil;

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] 
                                                          autorelease];
    decimalSymbol = [formatter decimalSeparator];

    ...
```

Comment: Can you say more about the actual risk that the GCC warning serves to point out? Assuming the zeroing of the object memory happens at alloc time (which I believe is right), it seems that only a @public or @protected ivar would be at risk of being clobbered by a superclass's `init` method, necessitating the warning. I can't think of why the warning would be useful for a private ivar, except stylistically, but that's not usually the compiler's concern.

Comment: @quixoto: +alloc does zero out memory. I've got no idea why it's important either... It may have something to do with the fact that a call to `[super init]` may return `nil`, and if it does then all `[sub init]` methods should also return `nil`. Other than that I wouldn't have a clue why GCC would care.

Answer (score 2):

The warning means what it says. You are assigning something to `decimalSymbol`, which is an instance variable, but at that point *there is no instance*. You need a

```
self = [super init];
```

At the start of your init method. At some point the object has to be created, at some point this has to call back to NSObject (via a chain of super inits).

Comment: It's a little strong to say "there is no instance." `alloc` should have already created the instance. The problem is that the instance may not have been correctly initialized (since that is what `init` does).