# Instance variable used while 'self' is not set to the result of

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, self

I'm working with SGAREnvioroment, and I get the following error:

**Instance variable used while 'self' is not set to the result of '[(super or self) init...]'**

In this piece of code:

```
@interface SG3DOverlayView (Private)

- (id) initGLES;
- (void) drawView;
- (BOOL) createFramebuffer;
- (void) destroyFramebuffer;

- (void) clearTouches;

@end

@implementation SG3DOverlayView

+ (Class) layerClass
{
    return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}

-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if(self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        self = [self initGLES];
    }

    return self;
}

-(id) initGLES
{
    self.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
    self.exclusiveTouch = YES;

    CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer*) self.layer;

    eaglLayer.opaque = YES;
    eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking,
                                    kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat,
                                    nil];

    context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];
    if(!context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context] || ![self createFramebuffer]) {
        [self release];
        return nil;
    }

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    mainSubview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    mainSubview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    animationInterval = 1.0;
    pinchTimer = nil;
    dragging = NO;
    currentSphereRadius = 0.0;

    [self clearTouches];

    return self;
}
```

I get the "error" here:

```
if(!context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context] || ![self createFramebuffer]) {
```

But, as you can see, self is setup on `-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame`, and `-(id) initGLES` is private, so it is always called from `-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame`.

So, may I have to do something to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't prefix your function name with init - the analyzer assumes that it's an initializer, and in this case it isn't.

Also, the function shouldn't return self if it isn't initialising it.  Make it void.

Comment: I've renamed from `intGLES` to `setUpGLES` and get another "error" in `-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` return statement (`return self`): `Returning 'self' while it is not set to the result of '[(super or self) init...]'`.

Comment: Don't do self = [self initGLES], just call [self initGLES].  You can only assign to self from an initializer (a function initializes and returns returns self). See http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-initializers.html.

Answer (score 1):

Similar questions/answers:

- [Obj-, Instance variable used while 'self' is not set to the result of '[(super or self) init...]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086996/obj-instance-variable-used-while-self-is-not-set-to-the-result-of-super-o)
- [Obj-C, Instance variable used while 'self' is not set to the result of '[(super or self) init...]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111549/obj-c-instance-variable-used-while-self-is-not-set-to-the-result-of-super)

And your `-(id)initGLES` looks more like `-(void)setupGLES`...